# Using absolute coordinates in 2D affine transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, transformation, affine-geometry

In my 2D animation program I have a sprite which transformation is described by a 2D affine transformation matrix ([SVGMatrix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InterfaceSVGMatrix)):

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & c & e \\
        b & d & f \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I'm trying to figure out how to set this sprite position to given screen coordinates:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

The sprite position is the position of sprite's *pivot point*, which is defined by sprite's transformation matrix.

For example, if a sprite of 64 x 64 pixels in size has this transformation matrix:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 32 \\
        0 & 2 & 32 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

...The sprite's pivot point is in its center, and the sprite is scaled x2.

The operation I look for, `set_position(x, y)`, should change sprite's transformation matrix in such way, so that the center (pivot point) of this sprite will be at $(x, y)$.

*(Unfortunately, I'm quite rusty on the topic and googling does not yield anything satisfactory. However, I feel that this is an embarassingly basic question...)*

Say, I want the sprite to appear at $(300, 200)$:

```
set_position(300, 200)
```

For a sprite with identity transformation matrix —not scaled, rotated, inverted or skewed, pivot at $(0, 0)$:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

...The result would be:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 300 \\
        0 & 1 & 200 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

If the sprite was scaled:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 2 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

...The result should take that in account:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 150 \\
        0 & 2 & 100 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Same thing for rotation, inversion and skew/shear.

That is, for a sprite of 64 x 64 pixels in size, this operation (in pseudocode) would move the sprite's pivot to its center and will rotate around the pivot by 90 degrees:

```
translate(32, 32)
rotate(π/2)
```

The corresponding matrix for the sprite:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1 & 32 \\
        -1 & 0 & 32 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Now, my `set_position(300, 200)` operation should change the sprite's transformation matrix so that the sprite's center (i.e. the pivot) would be at specified coordinates, $(300, 200)$.

Calculating expected `set_position()` result in this case will require some trigonometry, I guess, since sprite's coordinate system was rotated beforehand.

Looks like I'm missing something. Any clues on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

*Looks like this really is an embarrassingly simple question.*

Effectively, I need the translation to the given screen coordinates to happen before sprite's own transformation.

So, I need to multiply translation matrix for the coordinates that I need the by sprite's translation matrix, not vice-versa.

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & x \\
        0 & 0 & y \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
        \times 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & c & e \\
        b & d & f \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
$$

*Doh.*